# IllegalStateException randomely throwed at activity launch

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-theme, android-studio-2.0-beta5

When I run my activity, I get an `IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme` at random times. I just need to rebuild the project and the activity start on the next run, but after some runs, I get the exception again.

I checked that my application and activities themes inherit from `Theme.AppCompat`. All my activities extends `FragmentActivity`

I get the exception on API 22 (Android 5.1.1) and I am running Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5

**Edit**

I used Android Studio 1.5 and I did not get the error. It seems that on AS 2.0,  `super` in my Activities refers to `AppCompatActivity` and not to the inherited class `FragmentActivity`. I can't understand this behavior

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.heyway.heywayandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".HeyWayApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".login.FacebookLoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TriangleBackground">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".configuration.ConfigurationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_configuration"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TriangleBackground" />
        <activity android:name=".home.HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TriangleBackground" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_full</item>
    </style>
```

All my activities extends this class :

```
public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I should report this as a bug or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: "All my activities extends FragmentActivity" -- either change them to extend `AppCompatActivity`, or stop using `Theme.AppCompat`. `Theme.AppCompat` is for use by `AppCompatActivity`, not `FragmentActivity` or `Activity`.

Comment: FragmentActivity and Theme.AppCompat -- is causing the issue. I second CommonsWare solution here.

Comment: I had the same problem with AppCompatActivity. Actually I changed from AppCompatActivity after seeing the issue

Comment: Also, when I change something in the manifest, the error doesn't show on the next launch. I am wondering if the new quick build feature of Android Studio isn't responsible for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest you are missing the **minSdk** and **targetSdk** entries. Set the min and target sdk versions. Also make sure you included the **support libraries**. If That didnt worked out, also try with Holo Themes and see if the error comes.

Comment: The minSdk and targetSdk are set by gradle. The support libraries are included. If I could avoid to use Holo them it would be great also.